# Ghost installation on Digital Ocean - Error: "You are recommended to have at least 150 MB of memory available for smooth operation.""

Tags: digital-ocean, ghost-blog

I've set up a Droplet on Digital Ocean, and have launched the Droplet Console to complete installation of Ghost, but I received this error:

```
✔ Checking system Node.js version - found v16.17.0
✔ Checking current folder permissions
✖ Checking memory availability
✔ Checking free space
One or more errors occurred.

1) SystemError

Message: You are recommended to have at least 150 MB of memory available for smooth operation. It looks like you have ~138.6953125 MB available.
```

[This website](https://mrvautin.com/ghost-you-are-recommended-to-have-at-least-150-mb-of-memory-available/) says run this command this when you get this error:

```
ghost update --no-mem-check
```

But when I do that I get the response:

```
Working directory is not a recognisable Ghost installation.
```

Any help on how I can get past the initial system error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was solved after I added swap space to the server.

Instructions are found here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-22-04#step-4-enabling-the-swap-file